# Ajax, laravel - call function from controller in blade template

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

How to call a function

> storeSessionData( $name , $value) @sessionController

from

> partList.blade

with ajax?

I am quite confused, what route should i use to call ajax function if i have mutiple urls to 1 template. Maybe anyone would be so kind and write me an example how to do it?

**SessionController**

```
 public function storeSessionData( $name , $value){




       switch ($name) {
         case 'cpu':
          \Session::put($name,$value);
          break;
           case 'cpu_cooler':
             \Session::put($name,$value);
           break;

           case 'case':
             \Session::put($name,$value);
           break;   

            case 'motherboard':
             \Session::put($name,$value);
           break;  

                case 'psu':
             \Session::put($name,$value);
           break;    

          case 'memory':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;

          case 'sound_card':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;  

          case 'wireless_card':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;  

          case 'wired_card':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;  


           case 'storage':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break; 

              case 'optical_drive':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;

              case 'gpu':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;

              case 'case_fan':
          \Session::push($name,$value);
           break;

       }

             return redirect()->route('compatibilityCheck');

       }
```

**Partlist.Blade**

```
                @foreach ($parts as $part=>$value)
                @foreach ($value as $desc => $val)


                <th><a href="?sort={{$desc}}&order=asc">{{trans('specifications.' .$desc)}}</a></th>
                @endforeach
                @break
                @endforeach
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                @foreach ($parts as $part => $value)
                 <tr>
                @foreach ($value as $desc => $val)


                @if($val == reset($value))
               <td class="part-link" ><a href="{{$slug}}{{$value->slug}}">{{$val}} </a></td>
                @elseif ($val == end($value))

         <td><a class="button button-primary" href="" // Call ajax function on click {{$session_name}} {{$value->slug}} >Pievienot </a></td>

                @else 

        <td data-title="{{trans('specifications.' .$desc)}}:">{{$val}}</td>
                @endif
@endforeach
        </tr>

@endforeach
```

**partlist controller**

```
class partListController extends Controller
{   
     public function showAllCpu(Request $request){

// cpu query
$parts = // part query
$parts = $parts->paginate(30);

      $data = [
    'title' => '',
    'parts' => $parts,
    'slug' => 'procesors-',
    'bgImg' => 'cpubg',
    'headTitle' => 'Intel un AMD Procesori',
    'headParagraph' => 'Izvēlies jaunākos un izcilākos procesorus',
    'session_name' => 'cpu',


    ];

    if ($parts->currentPage() <= $parts->lastpage()) {
        return view('partlist', $data);
    } else{
      abort(404, 'Lapa nēeksistē');
    }
   }




  public function showAllMemory(Request $request){


// part query
$parts = // part query
$parts = $parts->paginate(30);

      $data = [
    'title' => 'Izvēlies operatīvo atmiņu',
    'parts' => $parts,
    'slug' => 'operativa-atmina-',
    'bgImg' => 'memorybg',
    'headTitle' => 'Operatīvā atmiņa',
    'headParagraph' => 'Paātrini sava datora ātrdarbību',
    'session_name' => 'memory',
    ];

    if ($parts->currentPage() <= $parts->lastpage()) {
        return view('partlist', $data);
    } else{
      abort(404, 'Lapa nēeksistē');
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example :

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('sessions/{name}/{value}', ['as' => 'session.store', 'uses' => 'SessionController@storeSessionData']);
```

**SessionController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SessionController extends Controller
{
    public function storeSessionData($name, $value) {
        // Do something with $name and $value

        return ['name' => $name, 'value' => $value];
    }
}
```

**partlist.blade.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    ...
  </head>
  ...
  <td><a class="button button-primary save-session" data-url="{{ route('session.store', ['name' => $session_name, 'value' => $value->slug]) }}">Pievienot</a></td>
  ...
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.save-session').on('click', function(){
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
      $this = $(this),
      url = $this.data('url');

    $.post(url, { _token: token }).done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    });
});
```